# Artin on the associative law of $n$ elements

Tags: group-theory

On page 40 of the first edition of Artin, he writes:

> Going back to a general law of composition, suppose we want to define a product of a string of $n$ elements of a set: 
>   $$a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n = ?$$
>   There are various ways to do this using the given law, which tells us how to multiply two elements. For instance, we could first use the law to find the product $a_1 a_2$, then multiply this element by $a_3$, and so on: 
>   $$((a_1 a_2)a_3)a_4 \ldots.$$
>   **When $n = 4$, there are four other ways to combine the same elements; $(a_1 a_2)(a_3 a_4)$ is one of them.**

My confusion is on the bold statement. I do not see where Artin gets that there are five ways to combine the numbers $a_1, \ldots a_4$. I get, for example: 
\begin{align*}
& ((a_1 a_2)a_3)a_4 \\
& ((a_2 a_1)a_3)a_4 \\
& ((a_3 a_1))a_2)a_4 \\
& ((a_3 a_1))a_4)a_2 \\
& \vdots \\
& (a_3 a_4)(a_1 a_2) \\
& (a_1 a_4)(a_2 a_3) \\ 
& \vdots 
\end{align*}
and so on. There are too many to write out on this page.

Where does Artin get that there are five ways? Am I misinterpreting him?

Comment: There are five ways **in the order** $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$.  This is an associative law discussion, not commutative.

Comment: $(((a_1a_2)a_3)a_4)$, $((a_1(a_2a_3))a_4)$, $(a_1((a_2a_3)a_4))$, $((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4))$,  $(a_1(a_2(a_3a_4)))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artin is not commuting the elements, he is only changing the location of the parentheses.